# Limit link width in relative div

Tags: html, css

The code below shows a tooltip when hovering over links. For some reason, I can't limit the width of the link inside of the div, so the hover effect happens at any point along the width of the parent div, which isn't what I want. I want the hover effect to be limited to the width of the link's text.

```css
.show {
  position: relative;
}


.show a {
    max-width: 20%;
}

.show .tooltip {
  /*visiblity: hidden; */    
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:5%;
  margin-top: -30px; /* approx adjustment for arrow */
  margin-left: 25px; /* approx adjustment for arrow */
}

.show a:hover + .tooltip, 
.show a:focus + .tooltip {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  /*visibility: visible; */
  width: 75%;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  color: rgb(113, 157, 171);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 1px 1px 1px;
  box-shadow: #333 -4px 4px 16px 2px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.show .tooltip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #FFFFFF transparent transparent;
  top: 22px;
  left: -23px;
}

a {
  max-width: 20%;
  max-width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="lev2">                    
  <div class="show">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><h3>Link</h3></a>
    <div class="tooltip">
      <h2>h2</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Edit: Switching the `a` or `h3` element to inline block changes the dimensions of the div, giving an unwanted margin and/or padding. Setting margin/padding of all elements involved to 0 doesn't resolve this.

Before:
[image: before inline-block]

After:
[image]

Comment: inline-block to the link element to be able to apply width/max-width OR inline-block to the heading to have a shrink to fit behavior

Comment: Thanks, that indeed limits the width of the link. However, increases the height of the div?

Comment: there is the default margin of h3

Comment: Weird, I thought I changed that margin to 0 in testing, but apparently not. Thanks, that did it!